# Open AI API Key missing

Tags: typescript, azure, next.js, openai-api, azure-openai

I have been using open ai for a while in many projects, today i created a new apiKey for my new project, whene i initialize open ai i get this error:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: The OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable is missing or empty; either provide it, or instantiate the OpenAI client with an apiKey option, like new OpenAI({ apiKey: 'My API Key' }).

code:

```js
import OpenAI from 'openai';

export const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env['OPENAI_API_KEY'], // This is the default and can be omitted
});
```

The apiKey is in my .env and also in my openAi portal

Whats happening??

Thanks!!

Comment: refer to  Azure OpenAI Service [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/). which open api u are using? . You can find  API Access control/Keys/access keys in the Azure portal in the Open API service. Search for API Access control/Keys/access keys.